# How to interrogate emails on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, email

It is possible to get the details of all emails on an iPad/iPhone by using Cocoa Touch?

I want to read the details of emails (Dates etc) and do analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the default mail.app but you can write your own email client.